# Programly scroll list box

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

My problem is that i have NewsList box:

[image]

Taping on some Item it will open aticle page with full article.

So, when i return back on News Page i see the List Box as it was before i navigated to the article, but i want **item which was used appear on top**

1) Changing the index doesn't do because they must remain as they are.

I Have tried:

```
if (currentArticle < NewsListBox.SelectedIndex)
{
    var scrollViwer = GetScrollViewer(NewsListBox) as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViwer != null)
    {

        scrollViwer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViwer.VerticalOffset + (NewsListBox.SelectedIndex - currentArticle));
    }
    currentArticle = NewsListBox.SelectedIndex;
}
else if (currentArticle == NewsListBox.SelectedIndex)
{
}
else
{
    var scrollViwer = GetScrollViewer(NewsListBox) as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViwer != null)
    {
        scrollViwer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViwer.VerticalOffset - (currentArticle - NewsListBox.SelectedIndex));
    }
    currentArticle = NewsListBox.SelectedIndex;
}

public static DependencyObject GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject o)
{
    // Return the DependencyObject if it is a ScrollViewer
    if (o is ScrollViewer)
    { return o; }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(o); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(o, i);

        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
        if (result == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works but it doesnt place element correctly on top if previous element wasn't correctly on top - which is impossible when user will do scrolling.

**ADDITION:**

```
NewsListBox.ScrollIntoView(NewsListBox.Items[5]);
```

works fine, but it shows element on bottom, i need on top.

**ADDITION 2:**

This would work fine:

```
NewsListBox.ScrollIntoView(NewsListBox.SelectedIndex+OFFSET);
```

I need help to calculate this offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `ScrollViewer`, but when I need to re-arrange the order of the items in a UI container control such as a `ListBox`, I simply re-arrange the order of the items in the data collection object that is bound to the control and the items in the control follow that order.

You could order them by date (and time) as @terasato suggested or just move the selected item to the first position in the collection using an `Insert` method.

Apologies if I have missed your point.

After reading your question again, I see a line saying that the indices of the collection objects must stay the same. If by that you mean that you cannot sort the original collection, then you will need to sort another collection copied from the original collection.

I often do this to allow a user to filter a collection of objects while still keeping the original collection of objects unchanged. You have two choices; either create another property of the same type as your collection in your code behind/view model and copy the original collection into that, or use a xaml `CollectionViewSource` object to sort the objects in the UI.

Comment: I found a solution, maybe not perfect but it works:


    scrollViwer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
                          scrollViwer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(NewsListBox.SelectedIndex);

Comment: How about putting that into an answer and marking this question as 'answered'?

Comment: LOL. Sorry, I didn't mean for you to mark my answer as correct, I meant to mark your own correct answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, maybe not perfect but it works: scrollViwer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0); scrollViwer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(NewsListBox.SelectedIndex);

Answer (score 0):

How about adding "UsedDate" property of "DateTime" that indicates the lastest used date, and sort the ListBox by UserDate.

Comment: If there were 2 articles in a same date? And i said i cant sort them - they must remain as they are

Comment: There is also a time portion of a `DateTime` object that could differentiate between the times that the various articles were viewed (even on the same day).